# How to transfer files from a host machine to a shared virtual machine in vmware workstation quickly?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware

This is what it looked like when you could set a shared folder with a unshared virtual machine -

[image]

And now with the VM as a shared virtual machine the shared folders option is gone along with a whole bunch of other things -

[image]

How do you still use shared folders or is there another way to transfer files from the host computer quickly?

P.S. I'm using vmware workstation 10.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, the shared folders should work, but it looks like you've already tried that one.  I would recommend trying a tool like SSH, rsync, a samba share, an NFS share, or something similar.  Since all the traffic is still local it should be pretty snappy.

Good luck.

Comment: I wasn't aware SSH was used for file transfer. My understanding was that it was for more of command line stuff. Do you have specific tutorials/apps to recommend to implement these? I can go ahead and try them and see if they get the job done quickly.

Comment: @Aki you can transfer files over SSH with [SCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) or [SFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol). I can't recommend any Windows software to enable them, though. FileZilla and WinSCP are good client apps, but you'll also need a server.

Comment: SCP and SFTP server apps?

Answer (score 0):

If solutions proposed by @tbenz9 won't work for you or you want to set it up quick, you can set up Dropbox or something like that. It's far from perfect solution and it won't be as fast (it won't copy on-the-fly, but will upload to the could first and then download and your space is limited) but you can literally have it working in few minutes and it's guaranteed to work as long as your VM has Internet access.

Comment: Dropbox wouldn't be such a implausible solution for small files but for folders at 6gb or higher I think it would be too slow.

Answer (score 0):

Shared folders will NOT work if you did not install VMware Tools on the virtual machine.
If your shared folder doesn't appear, try to install VMware Tools.
It worked for me.

If you've already installed VMware tools, try to update or reinstall it.